# how "cancan" gem process depth nested resource ability?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, cancan

here is my ability define:

```
can :manage,Order,:store => {:business_district => {:district_manager_id => user.id}}
```

and when I loading resourses by:

```
Order.accessible_by(current_ability)
```

It generate SQL like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `orders` INNER JOIN `stores` ON `stores`.`id` = `orders`.`store_id` INNER JOIN `business_districts` ON `business_districts`.`id` = `stores`.`business_district_id` WHERE (`stores`.`business_districts` = '---\n:district_manager_id: 37\n')
```

The sql looks all good except code in "where".
I don't know how to make it works
here is the model relation

```
1. store belongs_to business_district
2. order belongs_to store
3. business_district has district_manager_id
```

and i want see all orders in business_district

I have found a topic about this in so:[CanCan deeply nested resources
but when use block define in cancan ,you can't use accessible_by(current_ability) load resources!
and your can use `Order.joins(:store => :business_district).where("district_manager_id = ?",current_user.id)`to load what I want! is there any way cancan gem can do like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update (28 May):** *The pull request adding deeply nested resource abilities was included in the 1.6.10 release. There is also a [fix](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/pull/871) on GitHub for the SQL conditions bug described below. It should make it into the next release I believe, as it is an obvious mismatch.*

---

Maybe you've figured this out by now, but for anybody else who might stop by here before  searching the issues page for CanCan on github....

There's a pull request that was accepted about 2 months ago that addresses this. Check https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/pull/806 .

As of CanCan 1.6.9 this changeset wasn't incorporated so for now one has to use the master branch. As it stands though, the changeset introduces another bug from what I can tell, it fails for 2-condition ability definition, even in the non-nested case. For example, I've found that the following (I am using your models for naming...) fails:

```
can :manage, Order,:store => {:district_manager_id => user.id, :condition2 => true}
```

whereas the following is ok:

```
can :manage, Order,:store => {:district_manager_id => user.id }
```

I've also posted on the GitHub issue page about this.